# recognize the color of text(numbers) and save them to excel/text file by DM scripting

Tags: dm-script

In a DM format image, there is some text on it.

I would like to reach the function that could recognize the color of text, and save/export them to excel/txt file by scripting.  I mean the exported text will be sorted by their color in the Excel file.

How to reach it by DM scripting?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you mean the text-color on image annotations?
Text-annotations are just one kind of *component*, so the commands you are looking for are:

```
void ComponentGetBackgroundColor( Component comp, NumberVariable red_o, NumberVariable green_o, NumberVariable blue_o )
```

and

```
void ComponentGetForegroundColor( Component comp, NumberVariable red_o, NumberVariable green_o, NumberVariable blue_o )
```

Both will return the red, green and blue value of the component `comp` into the respective variables.

Comment: I use different color number text to represent different measurement, for example, red is height,  green is the width, purple is diagonal length， all them got a series of numbers. Then I  tried to save all these number text to a excel, but need to make all height (red) in a group, all the width(green text) in a group and purple text in a group in the excel, that helps me to get the mean values, standard deviation easily.  Thanks

Comment: @together wouldn’t it be easier to have the info in tagGroups/Taglists and then just create the annotations from that info? If color is a discerning property in your image info, you better make sure the user cannot change annotations. (You can make components non-editable)